# How to optimize GeoJSON file size before uploading to Mapbox Studio

Tags: mapbox

I have a GeoJSON file that I'd like to upload to Mapbox Studio as a tileset, so that I can use this custom data as a layer in my map style. The file is larger than the 300MB Studio upload limit. I know that I could use the [Uploads API](https://docs.mapbox.com/api/maps/#retrieve-s3-credentials) to upload it instead, or use [Mapbox Tiling Service](https://docs.mapbox.com/api/maps/#mapbox-tiling-service) to both optimize the data with a recipe, and upload it as a tileset, but I'm less familiar with the command line.

Is there another option to remove some data properties I don't need from my GeoJSON file (so that I can reduce the size below 300 MB) and then upload it to Mapbox Studio as a tileset?

Answer (score 2):

Following comments from 2018 on this [GIS Stack Exchange post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/12329/how-to-delete-fields-in-qgis), I was able to:

1. Add my GeoJSON file as a new Vector Layer in QGIS,
2. Select "Open Attribute Table" and click the "Delete field" icon mentioned in [this documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html) (see screenshot below). I then selected about half of my file's fields (which I don't need) and deleted them.
3. I right-clicked on my layer and exported it.

This cut my file size in half, and I was able to upload to Studio on the [tilesets page](https://studio.mapbox.com/tilesets/) in my Mapbox account!

[image]

It looks like another viable option to remove unnecessary fields using QGIS would be to go to Layer > Save As and only select certain fields I want to include (see screenshot below), and export the layer before uploading the optimized file to Studio.

[image]